# Repair disk with xfs_repair fails

Tags: centos, hard-disk, data-recovery, xfs

I am trying to repair a disk with `xfs_repair` after unmounting the disk as below. However I am still getting input/output error. I have some important data to recover. Is there any way to recover?

```
xfs_repair -L /dev/sdaa
Phase 1 - find and verify superblock...
superblock read failed, offset 3000590278656, size 131072, ag 3, rval -1

fatal error -- Input/output error
```

Comment: Anything IO related in `dmesg`? Looks like your storage is indeed dying and there's nothing `xfs_repair` can do about that. If that's the case you may want to copy data using ddrescue and then run `xfs_repair` on top of the restored data. Mind that if your storage is indeed failing now, using ddrescue may lead to more failures. Take your drive to a service center and ask them to image it.

Comment: I am seeing medium errors

Comment: Medium errors mean either the disk is failing oder the cabling to the disk ist broken. Nothing, any filsystem-check would be able to fix. So if reseating or exchanging the cable does not help, you would need a new disk. And restore your data from backup.